# Change format as integer in axis

Tags: jqplot

on my chart, on the xaxis and yaxis I have a wrong format:[image]

So, I would like that "00" will be "0", "08" will be "8", ""016" will be "16" and so on.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I find error.
I set `min:'0'` (as a string) instead of `min : 0`